# Can a Renault Megane drive 1700 km with 1 tank?

Tags: road-vehicles, consumer-products, advertising, fuel-economy

[image] <sup>[source](http://adoholik.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/renault_megane_paris-berlin.jpg)</sup>

See the above advert which claims that Renault Megane can cover 1700km with one tank.

According to this [link](http://carleasingmadesimple.com/business-car-leasing/renault/megane/fuel-tank-capacity/) the Megane model has a fuel tank capacity of 60 Liters.

Can the Megane cover 28.3 Kms per liter of petrol?

Comment: **Related question**: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/can-a-2000-honda-civic-get-41-mpg-17-5-km-litre

Comment: A [german car magazine](http://www.auto-motor-und-sport.de/fahrberichte/renault-megane-grandtour-sind-3-komma-5-liter-diesel-realisierbar-5034378.html) put the car to the test and fount that __6L/100km__ is more realistic (that means: ~ 1000 km/tank).

Comment: I believe the 'd' in 'dCi' stands for *diesel*, which would make the figure mildly less surprising.

Comment: I can get 20km/l (5 l/100km, 47mpg) out of one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=ford+focus+2003+tdci+estate), so I don't see much reason to doubt this figure. Though I guess you'd have to concentrate on your [driving style](http://www.ecodrive.org/). And not leave the aircon on.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Here's how: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XUKOUbp_PA

Answer (score 3):

According to Renault's figures, a Scenic with the dCI 110 engine can do up to [80.7 mpg](http://www.renault.co.uk/cars/model/meganesporttourer/ecoefficiency.aspx) or 34.3 Km/litre. This would allow a maximum theoretical limit of 34.3Km/litre × 60 litre/tank = 2058 Km/tank.

Here's how the figures are calculated:

> HOW ARE FUEL CONSUMPTION FIGURES CALCULATED?
>
> Official Fuel consumption figures are produced for comparison purpose and are measured according to the European Directive 80/1268/EEC. These figures are specific for a vehicle type and not for a single car. Real world fuel (actual) consumption can vary as the fuel efficiency of a vehicle is influenced by driving behaviour, weather and road conditions. The use of technical equipment for example air conditioning, can also effect the fuel consumption. For further information, please visit the Vehicle Certification Agency web site www.vca.gov.uk.

So it's a standard measurement, however it should be used fo *comparing car models* and not to *predict usage of a specific car*.

The ad seems to be misleading on that point.

Comment: What is misleading about the ad?  The ad says you can go 1700 km on a tank.  That is not the potential but actual road use  from my reading.  It even says what the route it used for it was.